# What kind of environment spawns the various starter pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I chose Squirtle as my starter, but actually did so to make it easier to capture Charmanders (as I expected that we needed to battle the wild pokemon). Other than my starter, I haven't seen any of the 3 starter pokemon at all.

I read about Pokemon being more likely to appear based on environment, and perhaps I can visit a beach or lakefront sometime to check if Squirtles are around. But where should I go to look for Charmanders or Bulbasaurs (and, would beaches actually have Squirtles there)?

I really don't plan to take a trip to Yellowstone for the nearest active volcano to hunt for Charmander / Charizard! Also my local park has a total lack of Bulbasaurs.

Comment: I hear fire pokemon can be found anywhere hot: primarily deserts, dry areas, and _beaches_.

Answer (score 1):

Small bodies of water would be enough for a squirtle and small patches of grass would even be enough for a bulbasaur. A buddy of mine told me he got charmander in the middle of the city so it seems he's easy to catch.

Now the starter Pokemon are quite rare to appear so it will take some time for them to spawn.

Comment: I got charmander in my bedroom